# Using Admanager Python API within a Colab Notebook

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-ad-manager

I am trying to get the Google AdManager API to work into a Colab notebook.

Following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/start) I have managed to create my own configuration YAML file, uploading it into the Colab notebook and executing the basic call to the `NetworkService` service. It all goes well and behaves as expected, returning the expected network name and ID.

Then I try to add some more requests like [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/ad_manager/v201811/line_item_service/get_all_line_items.py) and I get this error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleads/common.py in LoadFromStorage(path, product_yaml_key, required_client_values, optional_product_values)
        279   try:
    --> 280     with open(path, 'rb') as handle:
        281       yaml_doc = handle.read()


FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/googleads.yaml',

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

GoogleAdsValueError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ed9b34dcaa81> in <module>()
     25 if __name__ == '__main__':
     26   # Initialize client object.
---> 27   ad_manager_client = ad_manager.AdManagerClient.LoadFromStorage()
     28   main(ad_manager_client)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleads/ad_manager.py in LoadFromStorage(cls, path)
    202     return cls(**googleads.common.LoadFromStorage(
    203         path, cls._YAML_KEY, cls._REQUIRED_INIT_VALUES,
--> 204         cls._OPTIONAL_INIT_VALUES))
    205 
    206   def __init__(self, oauth2_client, application_name, network_code=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleads/common.py in LoadFromStorage(path, product_yaml_key, required_client_values, optional_product_values)
    282   except IOError:
    283     raise googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError(
--> 284         'Given yaml file, %s, could not be opened.' % path)
    285 
    286   try:

GoogleAdsValueError: Given yaml file, /root/googleads.yaml, could not be opened.
```

And this despite the fact that the same yaml file uploaded in the folder of the notebook (`content/googleads.yaml`) works perfectly well with the first request.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

PS: just to let you know, I am still in my infancy with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to help you if you included a minimal repro notebook showing what worked and what didn't.
Guessing in the dark, though: the thing that worked had extra code that looks in the current directory for the YAML file, while the thing that didn't doesn't.
Simplest fix might be to create a symlink like:

```
!ln -s /content/googleads.yaml /root/googleads.yaml
```

Comment: Both bits of code are one after the other in the same notebook, but the symbolic link did the trick, so thanks a lot for that!